# merge request guest into SE account

Tags: support, status-completed

At the beginning of this week i made a merge request as i wanted to merge a Question i by mistake asked as a guest i filled the form followed the instructions and got after 48h an email saying my account merge has expired pretending i didn't confirm the two accounts, which is false!

Now i tried to do it again and it seemed to work fine but instead of accepting to delete the guest account i was asked if i would confirm (by clicking on OK) to delete my SE account.

What can i do to merge this guest account into my regular account?

Comment: Can you give a link to the question with the unregistered user?

Comment: here it is http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5346/what-would-change-if-our-earth-lacks-mountains

Comment: Thanks, I've notified our community team about this and I'll update this when I hear back from them.

Answer (score 1):

Your request has been completed and your accounts properly merged.